# Release control to command line once forked process completes

Tags: ksh

I am new to Linux shell script programming and have written a script as below..

The Script runs fine, however after the program completes and echos that the program has completed I have to manually press [ENTER] on my keyboard to get the command line prompt. Why does my script behave like that?

What should I do so that when the child process completes, and the script echoes that the program has completed, the control is returned back to command line and I get the command line prompt without having to do anything?

```
#!/bin/ksh    
echo "program running..."

funcall(){    
  nohup <<command_name>> $program >/dev/null 2>&1      
  pid = $!      
  wait pid      
  echo "program completed..."      
  exit 
}

fork(){
  funcall &
}
fork
```

Answer (score 2):

It is highly unusual that a forked-off process waits for itself.

The flow of control should be

1. fork the process
2. child process does its thing
3. parent does its thing and waits

That would translate into something like

```
#!/bin/ksh

echo "program running..."

funcall () {    
  nohup some_command "$program" >/dev/null 2>&1      
  echo "program completed..."      
}

fork () {
  funcall &
}

fork
child_pid="$!"
wait "$child_pid"
```

Note that the backgrounding of the call to `funcall` and the waiting for the function call to return is totally unneeded in this case as the `fork` function is not doing anything while `funcall` is running.

What your code does is to start the child in the background and immediately return control to the parent shell.  The prompt may be a bit mixed up by the output from the script.

Note that you also have a couple of errors in your script:

1. `pid` is used as a variable, but should be `$pid`.
2. Assignment to `pid` should not have spaces around the `=`.

Also, the `exit` is not needed.

The trimmed down script that does what you need is

```
#!/bin/ksh

echo "program running..."
nohup some_command "$program" >/dev/null 2>&1      
echo "program completed..."
```

Answer (score 1):

After your process completes, you are already at the command prompt, but the prompt itself is obscured by the output from backgrounded portion the script.

Hitting enter will run whatever command you had typed on the command line (probably nothing) and then print the prompt again, seemingly "bringing your prompt back".

To clean up your screen after getting stray output on it, hit Ctrl-L.

Answer (score 0):

Change the code from  **`funcall&`** to **`funcall`**. Since the `funcall` is running in background, Parent process **ie. your script** is waiting to complete child process.

If you run funcall in foreground, your program exited normally.